# CSS animated background not working

Tags: css, animation

My animated background is not moving... and I can't figure out why...

the image appears properly, but nothing is moving....

my HTML:

```
<div class="section1">
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {    
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }    
    100% { background-position: 100% 0; }    
}    
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {    
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }    
    100% { background-position: 100% 0; }    
}    
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {    
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }    
    100% { background-position: 100% 0; }    
}    
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {    
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }    
    100% { background-position: 100% 0; }    
}    
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {    
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }    
    100% { background-position: 100% 0; }    
}    


.section1       {     
    background-image: url(mosaic.jpg);    
    background-position: 0px 0px;    
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;    
}
```

any help would be appreciated... thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hundred](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=css%20animation%20not%20working%20stack%20overflow) other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `-webkit` prefix for Safari, Chrome and Opera (which still [require](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) it):

```
.section1    {     
    background-image: url(mosaic.jpg);    
    background-position: 0px 0px;    
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
   -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;  
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;    
}
```